# React: content not fulfilling 100vh between aspect ratio

Tags: css, reactjs, vertical-alignment

I need this to fill the screen with no scroll bar

```
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 2/3) and (max-aspect-ratio: 3/2) {
  .containerMedia {
    columns: 3 auto;
  }
  .individualBoxMedia{
    height: calc(100vh/3);
  }
```

but its like this
[image: see white bars on bottom. not filling vh]

but this is working

```
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 2/3) {
  .containerMedia {
    columns: 2 auto;
  }
  .individualBoxMedia{
    height: 25vh;
  }
}
```

[image: working fine]

full code
App.js

```
//import logo from './images/logo512.png';
import './App.css';
import cardData from './data/cardData';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className='container containerMedia'>
        {cardData.map(card => {
          return (
            <div className='individualBox individualBoxMedia'>
              <div className='card'>
                  <div className='cardImageBox'>
                    <img src={card.location}/>
                  </div>
                  <div className='cardTextBox'>
                    <p>{card.text}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

/*

https://codesandbox.io/s/repeat-element-dpocp?file=/src/App.tsx

*/
```

app.css

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 2/3) {
  .containerMedia {
    columns: 2 auto;
  }
  .individualBoxMedia{
    height: 25vh;
  }
}
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 2/3) and (max-aspect-ratio: 3/2) {
  .containerMedia {
    columns: 3 auto;
  }
  .individualBoxMedia{
    height: calc(100vh/3);
  }
}
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 3/2) {
  .containerMedia {
    columns: 4 auto;
  }
  .individualBoxMedia{
    height: 50vh;
  }
}


.individualBox {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1vw;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.card{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5vw;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.cardImageBox{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
}

.cardTextBox {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 0;
  min-height: 40%;
  max-height: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  column-gap: 0rem;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

.individualBox img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position:top;
  border-radius: 0.5em 0.5em 0px 0px;
}
.individualBox p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

data

```
//Card Data
export default [
    {
        text: 'The final Computer Space design uses no microprocessor; the entire computer system is a state machine made of 7400-series integrated circuits, with monochrome graphic elements held in diode arrays.',
        location: './images/object1.jpg',
    },
    {
        text: 'object2 rtxyculvy fvgbhjn fcvgbhjn vybhnj ytbjhk xdcfvgbjh ctryvb crtfyvgbh',
        location: './images/object2.jpg',
    },
    {
        text: 'object3 cytvub tcvb tcfvyg trcvyb trcyvub yvtub yvtuby vytub vtuyb vtgubh vuybi',
        location: './images/object3.jpg',
    },
    {
        text: 'object4 tdrfygu ctryvbuu rtcyvbuni rtyvbu ed5rftyguhijo rextcvyb rtcyguhi rftyguhi',
        location: './images/object4.jpg',
    },
    {
        text: 'object5 cvgb ytvubiu rytui rytguhi rtfyguhijo rtfyguhijo zwxretcfyvguhio drftyg',
        location: './images/object5.jpg',
    },
    {
        text: 'object6 yvubyhinj ctryvuy rctyvub yrctvubiu rctyfugi f7tygiu rctvyubiu rftyguih',
        location: './images/object6.jpg',
    },
    {
        text: 'object7 cfvgbjhkn cfvygtbyhn rxectfvygbuni rtcvybun rctyvbuin rtyvub etcrvytgbu',
        location: './images/object7.jpg',
    },
    {
        text: 'object8 cvbyn rcytvubu trcyvubu rfytgui ytugi yrtvubi ytvubi yrctui ytui rfytugih',
        location: './images/object8.jpg',
    }
];
```

Comment: Are you definitely wanting the sort of layout that columns gives you or could you make do with CSS grid?

Comment: Please could you make your code into a snippet that we can run to see the problem? At the moment I cannot reproduce your problem with a simple HTML/CSS set up.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using something like this

```
.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: (auto, minmax(250px, 300px))
}
```